# How to change from string to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, casting, int

I need to create the function that changes a string of comma separated integers with this structure:

```
signal = ('1,7,6,9,12,21,26,27,25')
```

If I use this code, two-digit numbers is not correct, because it results in the separation into two numbers

```
result = [int(i) for i in signal]
```

Current output: `[1, 7, 6, 9, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 6, 2, 7, 2, 5]`

Expected output: `[1,7,6,9,12,21,26,27,25]`

Answer (score 3):

`type(signal)` will tell you data type of `signal` is still `str`. Take a try of below

```
x = signal.split(',')
[int(i) for i in x]
```

Comment: This gives output as a list of strings, and not integers

Answer (score 2):

In fact, your code raises a `ValueError` when trying to convert `','` to an `int`, you probably have a `tuple` of strings in your actual code (`string = ('1','7','6','9','12','21','26','27','25')`, in which case your code should work fine), if not, then another problem is that you're converting each character of the string separately, you should `split` the string by a comma first (to avoid the `ValueError` and to convert each *number* rather each *digit* to `int`):

```
signal = '1,7,6,9,12,21,26,27,25'

result = [int(i) for i in signal.split(',')]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 7, 6, 9, 12, 21, 26, 27, 25]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Shortest method using `eval`

```
list(eval(signal))
```

Testing:

```
>>> signal = ('1,7,6,9,12,21,26,27,25')
>>> 
>>> list(eval(signal))
[1, 7, 6, 9, 12, 21, 26, 27, 25]
>>>
```

---

#### Or another one using `eval`:

```
eval("[" + signal + "]")
```

Testing:

```
>>> signal = ('1,7,6,9,12,21,26,27,25')
>>> 
>>> eval("[" + signal + "]")
[1, 7, 6, 9, 12, 21, 26, 27, 25]
>>>
```

---

#### Heres another similar solution:

```
list(map(int, signal.split(",")))
```

Testing:

```
>>> signal = ('1,7,6,9,12,21,26,27,25')
>>>
>>> list(map(int, signal.split(",")))
[1, 7, 6, 9, 12, 21, 26, 27, 25]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to your question:

```
signal = ('1,7,6,9,12,21,26,27,25')
```

1. first use **split** to make a list from your string base on ',' character and then use **int** to change the type of output.

```
print([int(x) for x in signal.split(',')])
```

2. another way you can use the **map** to applying **int** to the list that created by **split** method.

```
print(list(map(int, signal.split(','))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code helps:

```py
result = [int(i) for i in signal.split(',')]
print(result)
```